# Java - Scanner not asking for a input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
System.out.println("Please enter the amount of money you have here: ");
Scanner have = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter your starting bet here: ");
Scanner rate = new Scanner(System.in);

int moneyHad = Integer.parseInt(have.next());
int moneyRate = Integer.parseInt(rate.next());
System.out.println(moneyHad + ", " + moneyRate);
```

There is my code, and this is my output.

```
Please enter the amount of money you have here: 
Please enter your starting bet here: 1
1
1, 1
```

As you can see it prints them both before it asks, thats why there was no input for line 1 of the output.

Please help me quickly!

Comment: Why are you creating two `Scanner` objects?

Comment: Just take a look at the order of the lines of code, and think about what each line does. Or use a debugger, for an even deeper insight. Shouldn't be too hard to get where the problem lies once you've done that. And a hint on `Scanner`: multiple Scanners on the same `InputStream` are quite likely to cause some issues and there's no need for two Scanners in the first place.

Comment: Abubakkar Rangara, its because I need 2 inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- No need to create 2 Scanner Object
- There is a method that returns int ( scanner.nextInt() ) no need to ParseInt
- The input is red when you call the scanner.nextInt() not when creating a     Scanner Object

Try this :

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter the amount of money you have here: ");
        int moneyHad = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Please enter your starting bet here: ");
        int moneyRate = scanner.nextInt();


        System.out.println(moneyHad + ", " + moneyRate);
```

Comment: Plus why do you only need one scanner.

Answer (score 1):

you need just one scanner object and call `nexInt()` method to get the followed entry.

Comment: Yeah I saw that in the comment above.